# Expose an OSGi Service as Camel Endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I don't even know if I formulated the question the right way around ;-)

What I basically want to achieve is something like this:

```
<route >
    <from uri="osgi:serviceName"/>
    <!-- do some processing ->
    <to uri="activemq:queue:inbox"/>
</route>
```

So I'd like to have an OSGi Service as starting point of my route. This service can be referenced by some other bundles and *fed* with input data, that will be later on processed by the Route.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply create an OSGi service outside of camel and a route that starts with direct:anyname. Then you can inject a ProducerTemplate into your service an call the route from there.

Comment: Can you please explain this "inject a ProducerTemplate into your service" in a little bit more detail? Or maybe do you have an example? Cheers!

Comment: I think the easiest way is to inject the CamelContext and do ProducerTemplate producer = contrext.createProducerTemplate();

Answer (score 2):

If you have really simple method signature, or typeConverter for the parameters you want to pass, you can use [CamelProxy](http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html) to link the service to your route in a simple XML configuration file.

To extends the example of the doc, you would have something like :

```
<osgi:service id="service" ref="myProxySender"                             (4)
      interface="org.apache.camel.spring.config.MyProxySender" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- create a proxy that will route to the direct:start endpoint when invoked -->
    <proxy id="myProxySender"
           serviceInterface="org.apache.camel.spring.config.MyProxySender"
           serviceUrl="direct:start"/>

    <!-- this is the route that our proxy will routed when invoked
         and the output from this route is returned as reply on the proxy -->
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <transform>
            <simple>Bye ${body}</simple>
        </transform>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use "osgi" as the URI scheme in a Camel route, you would need to create a custom Camel component to handle invoking the relevant OSGi commands.  For more information, please see http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html

A simpler alternative would be to write custom OSGi commands that used a ProducerTemplate to send messages to a Camel route.  An example for Karaf can be found here: https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/demos/command

Injecting a ProducerTemplate can be done via standard Spring configuration.